# How to get the client certificate or more precisely the client DN in GRPC++?

Tags: c, ssl, grpc

I have clearly understood how to establish a two-way authenticated SSL communication in GRPC++,but now I desire to obtain the way to get SSL client DN in the established TLS communication to make a further identity status classification.
Thanks if you have some suggestions.

Comment: One thing more,I hope the way can confirm which connection among many rpc connections is sent by whose client.So the way should be able to get something I need from the existing connection rather than require client send its certificate agin by rpc ways even if it is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the peer certificate chain from gRPC AuthContext, under the property name (GRPC_X509_PEM_CERT_CHAIN_PROPERTY_NAME).

Comment: I find this which you mean maybe, but it's not useful .`context->Auth_Context()->FindPropertyValues("x509_pem_cert")->front()->data()`